# Upstart: Error when using command substitution in post-start script stanza during startup sequence

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sh, upstart

I'm seeing an issue in upstart where using command substitution inside a post-start script stanza causes an error (syslog reports "terminated with status 1"), but only during the initial system startup.

I've tried using just about every startup event hook under the sun. local-filesystems and net-device-up worked without error about 1/100 tries, so it looks like a race condition. It works just fine on manual start/stop. The command substitutions I've seen trigger the error are a simple cat or date, and I've tried using both the $() way and the backtick way. I've also tried using sleep in pre-start to beat the race condition but that did nothing.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on VMWare with a Win7 host. Spent too many hours troubleshooting this already... Anyone got any ideas?

Here is my .conf file for reference:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

env NODE_ENV=production
env MYAPP_PIDFILE=/var/run/myapp.pid

respawn

exec start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile $MYAPP_PIDFILE --chuid node-svc --exec /usr/local/n/versions/0.6.14/bin/node /opt/myapp/live/app.js >> /var/log/myapp/audit.node.log 2>&1

post-start script
    MYAPP_PID=`cat $MYAPP_PIDFILE`
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] + Started $UPSTART_JOB [$MYAPP_PID]: PROCESS=$PROCESS UPSTART_EVENTS=$UPSTART_EVENTS" >> /var/log/myapp/audit.upstart.log
end script

post-stop script
    MYAPP_PID=`cat $MYAPP_PIDFILE`
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] - Stopped $UPSTART_JOB [$MYAPP_PID]: PROCESS=$PROCESS UPSTART_STOP_EVENTS=$UPSTART_STOP_EVENTS EXIT_SIGNAL=$EXIT_SIGNAL EXIT_STATUS=$EXIT_STATUS" >> /var/log/myapp/audit.upstart.log
end script
```

Comment: You don't really need a command substitution here, `date` can print stuff just fine.  `date -u +"[%Y-%M-%Dt%t.3NZ] - Started $UPSTART_JOB [$MYAPP_PID]: PROCESS=$PROCESS UPSTART_EVENTS=$UPSTART_EVENTS" >>/var/log/myapp/audit.upstart.log` ... assuming your variables don't contain any %-sequences which need to be escaped.

Comment: True, I may be able to avoid command substitution for date, but not for cat as far as I know. If I could find a way to get that PID into the log entry without command substitution then your right in saying I could circumvent the whole issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario I can think of is that `$MYAPP_PIDFILE` has not been created yet.

Because you have not specified an 'expect' stanza, the post-start is run as soon as the main process has forked and execed. So, as you suspected, there is probably a race between `start-stop-daemon` running node and writing that pidfile and `/bin/sh` forking, execing, and forking again to exec `cat $MYAPP_PIDFILE`.

The right way to do this is to rewrite your post-start as such:

```
post-start script
  for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do
    if [ -f $MYAPP_PIDFILE ] ; then
      echo ...
      exit 0
    fi
    sleep 1
  done
  echo "timed out waiting for pidfile"
  exit 1
end script
```

Its worth noting that in Upstart 1.4 (included first in Ubuntu 12.04), upstart added logging ability, so there's no need to redirect output into a special log file. All console output defaults to `/var/log/upstart/$UPSTART_JOB.log` (which is rotated by logrotate). So those echos could just be bare echos.

Comment: I like this line of thinking, but if I remove the cat command completely, the presence of the date command can still trigger the error.